# Struct variable changes value with printf

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a struct with an array of pointers to integers.  The value of the first pointer is changing between calls to printf.  This doesn't happen unless I generate the struct via a function.  The code is below.  Can someone tell me what's happening?  Thanks.

```
 struct a {

     int *nums[10];

 };

 struct a *makeS();


 int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

      struct a *_b = (struct a*) malloc(sizeof(struct a));

      struct a *_c = makeS();

      int i = 1;

      _b->nums[0] = &i;

      printf("Num is %d\n", *_b->nums[0]);  // prints 1
      printf("Num is %d\n", *_b->nums[0]);  // prints 1
      printf("Num is %d\n", *_b->nums[0]);  // prints 1
      printf("Num is %d\n", *_b->nums[0]);  // prints 1 … etc.


      printf("Num is %d\n", *_c->nums[0]);  // prints 1
      printf("Num is %d\n", *_c->nums[0]);  // prints 0
      printf("Num is %d\n", *_c->nums[0]);  // prints 0
      printf("Num is %d\n", *_c->nums[0]);  // prints 0 … etc.


  }

  struct a* makeS(){

      struct a *_s = (struct a*) malloc(sizeof(struct a));

      int i = 1;

      _s->nums[0] = &i;

      return _s;

 }
```

Comment: You are assigning `&i` to `_s->nums[0]`, but `i` stops existing the moment `makeS()` exits.

Comment: when memory is no longer held on to for any variables, then the details of the program structure (like whether you create stuff with a function or not) will impact exactly when what memory is overwritten.  Both situations are undefined as to what the behavior will be, but sometimes that undefined behavior is also the desired behavior -- but that's just luck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is in the function:

```
  struct a* makeS(){

      struct a *_s = (struct a*) malloc(sizeof(struct a));

      int i = 1;

      _s->nums[0] = &i;

      return _s;

 }
```

`int i` goes out of scope as it is a local variable, meaning you are using a dangling pointer.

The memory used by `i` is free to be used by something else, and is most probably repurposed by the buffer or working space used in the subsequent `printf` calls.

Comment: Thanks - very helpful :)